# C#: Create an array of classes

Tags: c#, class

I want to create a list of classes, from where I can build a "Toolbox" in my form. It boils down to a list of possible widgets that I can drag and drop into a `Panel`. The classes will implement the same interface and have some static methods to create the list.

Some code I have:

```
public interface IWidget {
   Image image { get; }
}

public class Gauge : IWidget, PictureBox {
   public static Image image {
       get {
           return Properties.Resources.gauge;
       }
   }
}
```

in the Form, I want to put an array like this:

```
IWidget[] supported_widgets = { Gauge };
```

and cycle over them to create the Toolbox the user can choose from, using the static methods in the classes, not by instantiating them (they will be instantiated when dropped on the `Panel`):

```
foreach (IWidget w in supported_widgets) {
    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    p.Image = w.getImage();

    toolbox.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

I experimented with `System.Type`, but it just feels a little overkill. What's the best way to do something like this? Is it even possible without instantiating the classes?

Comment: Interfaces should begin with an I... `IWidget` as opposed to `Widget`. It makes reading code easier to understand what is an interface and what is a class.

Comment: @m-y I know. I'll update my question.

Comment: Also, you can not implement an interfaces public member as a static. It must be implemented as an instance.

Comment: Incidentally, is there any reason you want to avoid instantiating the classes? I'm looking at your code sample, and the classes seem fairly small, so instantiation should be cheap.

Comment: @Mihai the only reason is that I always try to avoid things that are not necessary. I agree in this example the classes are small, but I don't know what will happen later.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help. Eventually I decided to create an array of instances anyway, setting the image in the constructor of the implementing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a list of classes

Taken literally that is simply not possible.

What you can do is create a list of objects (instances). That can be of the `Type` class that you already tried or you can create a helper class for each of your types.

```
 class WidgetHelper<T> where  T : IWidget, new() { }
```

and then you may want to add a little more functionality to `IWidget`.

Answer (score 2):

An `IWidget` represents an instance of a widget, so you can't pass it as a `IWidget[]` if you haven't instantiated them yet. `Type`, or `Type[]` should be fine - it isn't "overkill" - it is the appropriate and expected way of describing a type. Additionally, you can instantiate easily by just:

```
IWidget newInstance = (IWidget)Activator.CreateInstance(someConcreteWidgetType);
```

Comment: When using `Type`, I should use `GetMember()` to get the `Image` ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs no; the "static image" thing is a bad idea. In that scenario, the factory scenario on Mihai's answer makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `Type` objects, you can resort to [the Factory pattern:](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html)

```
public interface IWidgetFactory
{
    IWidget makeWidget();
} 

public class WidgetFactory<TWidget> : IWidgetFactory where TWidget : IWidget, new() 
{
    IWidget makeWidget()
    {
        return new TWidget();
    }
}

IWidgetFactory[] supported_widgets = { new WidgetFactory<Gauge>(), new WidgetFactory<Indicator>() };

foreach (IWidgetFactory wf in supported_widgets) {
    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    p.Image = wf.makeWidget().getImage();

    toolbox.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this would instantiate the class. That is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: My bad -- I just noticed that `getImage` is a static method of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Using Type is fine as Marc said, and you can use the activator to create the object (when you drop it in the Panel). If you want to use the static methods only to populate the Toolbox, so no class creation here, then use `GetMethod()` and `Invoke()`:

```
Type[] supported_widgets = { typeof(Gauge) };

foreach (var w in supported_widgets) {
    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    p.Image = w.GetMethod("getImage").Invoke(null, null);

    toolbox.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

Outside the scope of this answer are all the considerations about using Reflection and about having to use a string to pass the method name, which is brittle and not helpful when refactoring... Keep this in mind.